# Test Jest with babel-plugin-import

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, antd, babel-jest

Jest is breaking because of babel-plugin-import.  I'm using .less styles with Ant Design which I believe is causing it.  I'm new to the Jest library so I'm unsure the proper way to import or get around that issue?

**Example**:

```
Test Suite failed to run
Cannot find module 'antd/lib/skeleton/style' from 'index.js'
```

**.babelrc file**

```
 "plugins": [
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": true }],
```

I've tried a number of solutions like babel-jest, moduleNameMapper, etc. but there's a high probability I wasn't using them correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper answer to this is:

**In .babelrc:**

Separate out production, development and "test" within .babelrc underneath "env".  On production and development, leave babel-plugin-import just like it is.  On "test", make sure you remove it (Jest can't handle it).

**In Package.json**

You're welcome to configure Jest in this file, but the most important thing is on your NPM script for test, you pass it a `NODE_ENV=test jest` so that it sets the proper env that babel is going to reference.

**Docker/Virtualenv/Kubernetes users**

Finally, if you're using Docker/Kubernetes or some sort of tool that has packages installed anywhere outside of your local machine, make sure the packages are actually installed.....  I forgot so when I removed babel-plugin-import from "test" and started seeing an error for `antd is undefined` it made me scratch my head for a bit. As soon as I realized it was because Ant Design was only installed on my Kubernetes nodes and not actually on my computer where I was running the commands.  Dumb mistake, but easy one to make when you've seen error codes for hours.